# Dockerfile - Debian apt-get php-xdebug failing

Tags: xdebug, dockerfile, apt-get

I am trying to create a docker image that has the following:

- php7
- apache2
- git
- xdebug

In my dockerfile I have the official php7 with apache image as the base.
I can run apt-get update.
I have installed git successfully.
But when I run `apt-get install -y php-xdebug` I get the following:

```
E: Unable to locate package php-debug
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.0-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git

RUN apt-get install -y php-xdebug
```

Comment: I dont see an official php7-apache on docker hub, can you paste your Dockerfile ?

Comment: Sorry - it's the tag 7.0-apache in the official php repo.

Comment: Could you solve it ? Having the same problem here!

Comment: Ended up changing versions. Sorry I can’t help!